# Como apontar todas as páginas do site para uma página só?

Tags: htaccess

Estou precisando de uma solução em `htaccess` que aponte todas as páginas do site para uma página específica do tipo:

```
http://meusite.com.br/pagina1.html -> http://meusite.com.br/index.php
http://meusite.com.br/pagina2.html -> http://meusite.com.br/index.php
http://meusite.com.br/pagina3.html -> http://meusite.com.br/index.php
http://meusite.com.br/pagina4.html -> http://meusite.com.br/index.php
http://meusite.com.br/pagina5.html -> http://meusite.com.br/index.php
```

Gostaria de apontar todas as páginas para a home porque todo o site é em html e o único lugar que eu consegui um `.php` para redirecionar para outro site foi na home.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [R=permanent,L]
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522921/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-single-page)

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo criar um sistema de rotas, como mostrado aqui:
http://rberaldo.com.br/urls-amigaveis-sem-htaccess-usando-slim/

Seu `.htaccess` terá só isto:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

O resto será programado na `index.php`, que tomará conta de redirecionar para o local correto